# How can i show discount label on category page on products if there is special price?

Tags: magento2

I want to show discount label on category page on a product if there is special price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function $product->getSpecialPrice() function to check if special price is applied and based on that u can add discount label class. and in that class u can set icon.

Answer (score 0):

First of all copy list.phtml at below location from vendor module,

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Now add span or image based on condition as below

```
<?= $product->getSpecialPrice():'<span>Special</span>':''; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and decided to create extension for it
You can try to install it
https://github.com/boris1988/module-product-labels